# curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: DELETE; Unknown error

Tags: hadoop, centos7, hadoop-2.7.2

I am using hadoop apache 2.7.1 on centos 7 and I want to delete a file(file1) by using webhdfs commands.

```
curl -i -x DELETE "http://192.168.25.21:50070/webhdfs/v1/hadoophome/file1/?user.name=root&op=DELETE&recursive=true"
```

But I am getting this error:

```
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: DELETE; Unknown error
```

I edited bashrc file as following :

```
export http_proxy=""
export https_proxy=""
export ftp_proxy=""
```

And source the file to save changes

```
 source ~/.bashrc
```

But with the same error.

So I tried to set no proxy in the culr command as

```
curl -i -x --noproxy localhost  DELETE "http://192.168.25.21:50070/webhdfs/v1/hadoophome/file1/?user.name=root&op=DELETE&recursive=true"
```

With this error:

```
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: --noproxy; Unknown error
```

What should I edit to exclude this proxy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`-x` stands for proxy. You should be using `-X` to specify the request method.

So the command would be,

```
curl -i -X DELETE "http://192.168.25.21:50070/webhdfs/v1/hadoophome/file1/?user.name=root&op=DELETE&recursive=true"
```

Refer [curl(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) for options.